# HTML Using this.parentNode.querySelector

Tags: javascript

I am using `this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();` to minus the number in my input `value`, how to stop running `this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();` when the `value` reach `<= 0`?

Here is my coding https://jsfiddle.net/hong5305/495ty0gq/1/

```html
<div class="aaa-input">
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();">
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;"></div>
    title</a>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="number" value="5" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Avoid inlining JavaScript like that. It's prone to errors, and makes debugging and developing harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it by a single `if` statement, that check's whether the number input's value is greater than 0.

I recommend you to avoid using inline JS event listeners. Instead use something like the following. The JS part can also handle an arbitrary number of `.aaa-input`s without any code repetition:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
  for(const elem of document.querySelectorAll('.aaa-input')){
    elem.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {
      const numberInput = elem.querySelector('input[type=number]')
      if(numberInput.value > 0)
        numberInput.stepDown();
    })
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="aaa-input">
  <a>
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;">
    </div>
    title
  </a>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="number" value="5" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aaa-input">
  <a>
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;">
    </div>
    title
  </a>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="number" value="5" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty">
  </div>
</div>

<div class="aaa-input">
  <a>
    <div>
      <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;">
    </div>
    title
  </a>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="number" value="5" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I will learning on it. Beside that, If I loop the div like `<div class="aaa-input1">...</div><div class="aaa-input2">...</div>`, how do I adjust the javascript without loop the whole `documen.add...})` javascript?

Comment: Use the same class (e.g. `aaa-input` without a number at the end), snd use a JS loop. I'll edit my answer to be more detailed...

Comment: @SweeHong I've edited my post, take a look at it now!

Answer (score 1):

add `min` property to the input element. this should fix your problem.

```html
<div class="aaa-input">
  <a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();">
    <div><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;"></div>
    title</a>
  <div class="control-group">
    <input type="number" value="5" min="0" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check the value of the input before calling stepDown:

```
<a href="javascript:;" onclick="if(this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').value > 0)this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();"><div style="height:7em; line-height:7em;">
```

And your function will not be called when the input reach 0. However, as said by others in the comments, coding like that will lead to errors.

Answer (score 1):

The min attribute specifies the minimum value for an  element.

Tip: Use the min attribute together with the max attribute to create a range of legal values.

Note: The max and min attributes works with the following input types: number, range, date, datetime-local, month, time and week.

> Syntax

```
<input min="number|date">
```

Code -

```html
<div class="aaa-input">
   <div style="float:left; background: white;box-shadow:0px 0px 10px rgb(0,0,0,0.1); padding:0.5em; border-radius:10px; position:relative; margin-right:1em;margin-bottom:1em; font-size:0.9em">
    <a href="javascript:;" onclick="this.parentNode.querySelector('input[type=number]').stepDown();"><div style="height:7em; line-height:7em;">
     <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg" style="max-width:70%;">
    </div>title</a>
    <div class="control-group">
          <input type="number" value="5" name="prodqty[1]" id="prodqty" min='0'>
       </div>
   </div>
  </div>
```